# Cannot find firefox binary in PATH. Make sure firefox is installed. OS appears to be: WIN10

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, windows-10, environment-variables

I am getting following error. Can you advice.

```
`Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Cannot find firefox binary in PATH. Make sure firefox is installed. OS appears to be: WIN10
Build info: version: '3.13.0', revision: '2f0d292', time: '2018-06-25T15:32:14.902Z'
System info: host: 'CTSAUS-LT-641', ip: '10.243.111.75', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_172'
Driver info: driver.version: FirefoxDriver
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxBinary.<init>(FirefoxBinary.java:116)
    at java.util.Optional.orElseGet(Unknown Source)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxOptions.getBinary(FirefoxOptions.java:217)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.toExecutor(FirefoxDriver.java:161)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:125)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:103)
    at newpackage.MyClass.main(MyClass.java:11)`
```

Comment: @eisbehr PLease don't `<blockquote>` the error trace logs else debugging the error logs becomes difficult.

Comment: @Ritam, please add the code trial done by you as well

Comment: @RitamDutta Update the question with your code trials

Answer (score 1):

Do as error message tells you: Make sure firefox is installed.

Then check out, if it is configured properly, i.e. `firefox.exe` is in a directory which appears in your PATH environment variable. You can check it out with typing `echo %PATH%` in your command line.

See where Fiurefox is installed for example by right-clicking on your Firefox desktop icon and then checking "Properties" dialog to see where it is installed.

If for example `firefox.exe` is in directory `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox"` then this directory has to appear in the (semicolon separated) list of the PATH varaible.